# Como trazer no resultado do SELECT as condições inseridas como parâmetros?

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Tem alguma forma de trazer no resultado do `SELECT` os **valores dos parâmetros** utilizados na cláusula `WHERE` ?

Exemplo:

```
SELECT 
  a.*, cast(:dataIni as date) AS inidate , cast(:dataFin as date) AS inidate 
FROM 
  mytable a 
WHERE 
  a.date BETWEEN :dataIni AND :dataFin
```

Existe alguma forma de se retornar os valores dos parâmetros como campos da consulta utilizando o Firebird?

Comment: Não está muito claro o que você está perguntando. Por favor explique melhor.

Comment: Você deseja fazer um cast antes de enviar a data para validação?

Comment: Acredito que o que o AP quer, é trazer os valores dos parâmetros como campos da consulta

Comment: Provavelmente você está tentando resolver algum mistério. Conte-nos o objetivo de querer trazer o valor dos parâmetros no resultado da query e poderemos ajudar.

Comment: Não teria como fazer isso usando [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)? Não conheço muito de firebird pra saber se possui tal funcionalidade.

Comment: @gabrielhof Sim, Firebird possui prepared statements. Mas não entendi como isso se relaciona com trazer o valor dos parâmetros no resultado do Select.

Comment: Ele poderia passar isso como parâmetros na execução do statement. Mas de qualquer forma, seria necessário passar o mesmo parâmetro duas vezes (uma para o `select` e outra para o `where`). Como você respondeu, não faz sentido fazer isso, mas fiquei na dúvida se era possível fazer.

Comment: Seria um Problema XY?

Comment: Qual o ambiente de teste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito é so colocar os parâmetros como fields:

```
SELECT 
  a.*, 
  cast(:dataIni as date) AS inidate , 
  cast(:dataFin as date) AS inidate,
  :dataIni as DataInicial,
  :dataFin as DataFinal 
FROM 
  mytable a 
WHERE 
  a.date BETWEEN :dataIni AND :dataFin
```

Não sei se é isso que precisa!!!

Answer (score 0):

Não há como fazer isso.

Tampouco um recurso como este parece necessário pois quem enviou a consulta é também quem vai obter os resultados e este sujeito conhece os valores que passou como parâmetro.